# HTMLControl on WM 6.1 - VGA

Tags: html, windows, mobile, controls, vga

I am facing trouble enabling "High Resolution" mode in WM6
Professional. I am using a HTMLView.dll to embed an HTMLControl in our
application. By default the "HTML" Shown is not in "High Resolution"
Mode - The App is appearing all zoomed up and as how it is displayed
in lesser resolution Emulators/devices.(QVGA)

I have already referred to a few links suggested from folks. Most of
the links point to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa454895(v=msdn.10)

which offers a solution to turn off the Emulation layer in WM6 by
adding a line to the resource file.

HI_RES_AWARE CEUX {1} // To turn off the emulation layer

This is because of an accepted bug - discussed at -
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d3c837d-16f4-4ae4-acc2-96bb8d573111/htmlview-too-large-on-wm6-vga

Doing the HI_RES_AWARE didn't help as the view on the HTMLControl was
the same. I want to imitate the same functionality that IE Mobile does
when I select Menu->View->High Resolution, which does show the HTML
the way it's supposed to be shown (Smaller - so that more HTML View
screen is achieved).

I have already tried to modify the DTM_ZOOMLEVEL which I normally set
when an HTML is written to the HTMLControl - But even the least zoom
setting doesn't zoom out sufficiently. The view on the IE mobile's high
resolution mode is much better.

I have also tried getting the width and height of the screen by using
the GetDeviceCaps() method, but this only returns me the screen size,
which will at the max help me to modify my created window's size.

The issue that I am facing is how to enable the high resolution mode
automatically on my html pages (here I am not creating the UI for
mobile device, it's only the html page).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've researched a lot and from the resources and my experience. You're stuck with a QVGA resolution for the HTML Control on WM 6.1 - it's like hardcoded from Microsoft.

No point in dragging your quest forward. End it and re-design your UI to look good on QVGA resolution.